# Change mutability of function argument depending on const generic

Tags: rust

I am developing a CPU emulator in Rust. During normal execution, reading certain memory addresses has side-effects, therefore a `&mut` should be passed to the `read` function to allow for mutation of state.

However, for debugging purposes, I also have a trace unit which is given an immutable reference to the CPU and memory (reading should have no side-effects). At the moment, the `read` function looks something like this:

```rust
pub fn read<const SIDE_EFFECTS: bool>(memory: &mut CMem, addr: u16) -> u8 {
    match addr {
        0x0000..=0x1FFF => {
            if SIDE_EFFECTS {
                /* do something to memory with side-effects */
            } else {
                /* only "observe" something in memory */
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This function is OK, but actually, the case when `SIDE_EFFECTS` is `false` is somewhat redundant as the function signature itself requires a `&mut` irrespective of the value of `SIDE_EFFECTS`. What I really want is to have a parameter list conditional on the const generic. Something like (not real Rust code):

```rust
pub fn read<const SIDE_EFFECTS: bool>(memory: T, addr: u16) -> u8 
    where T: if SIDE_EFFECTS { DerefMut<Target = CMem> } else { Deref<Target = CMem> } {
    match addr {
        0x0000..=0x1FFF => {
            if SIDE_EFFECTS {
                /* do something to memory with side-effects */
            } else {
                /* only "observe" something in memory */
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Is something like this possible, or will I need to redesign?

Thanks

Comment: Not possible with const generics, but you can define different versions of the same function with conditional compilation (but would require a different build/binary be used for debugging—is this ok?)

Comment: But the debug build still needs both implementations - one for standard CPU emulation, one for the trace unit.

Comment: Perhaps then just use a trait, for example like in [this playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=4dfe521e91850a59d7703c34dcf354bd)?

Comment: That looks pretty good to me. Irritatingly, we're back to good-ol' Rust code duplication for `do_something`. I guess the solution there is to make `do_something` a lightweight wrapper over something else... let's see how it goes. Thanks.

Comment: To be honest, it can probably be [even simpler](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=1023cc69032daaef1d28436b6c02a983), but I think the code duplication issue is unavoidable (though of course you might be able abstract common behaviour, as you say).

Comment: @eggyal One challenge I'm facing with your even simpler approach is that the `read` function is eating up (moving) references, so constructs like `read(memory, addr) | read(memory, addr + 1)` won't compile. Any ideas here?

Comment: You'll need to change `read`'s signature, either to accept `&mut T` (where `T` is itself `&CMem` or `&mut CMem`) or else to return `T` (together with the existing `u8` return value, e.g. as a tuple `(T, u8)`, so that it can be extracted and reused in subsequent calls).  Neither is perfect, but I'm struggling to think of a better way.